# Shell script Sed ler um arquivo e escrever em outro apenas na primeira ocorrência de uma string

Tags: linux, terminal, shell-script

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando ler de um arquivo X e escrever num arquivo Y quando aparecer uma String especifica. Mas só quero fazer a inclusão uma vez. Exemplo que eu estou tentando fazer:

```
sed -i '/, pasta/r teste.txt' Report.html
```

Esse comando esta lendo todas as strings ", pasta" e esta incluindo embaixo o conteúdo do arquivo teste.txt. Mas eu quero fazer que ele inclua apenas na primeira ocorrência da string ", pasta" . Um comando do tipo:

```
sed -i '0,/, pasta/r teste.txt' Report.html
```

A sintaxe acima está errada, como seria a correta para incluir o conteúdo do arquivo apenas na primeira ocorrência da string ", pasta" ?

Answer (score 1):

Se é apenas para achar uma ocorrência, sem fazer substituições nem haver muitas condições para esse match ser verdadeiro, eu usaria o **grep**.

```
grep -o -a -m 1  -h  "pasta" teste.txt > report.html
```

Parametros:

-o = Mostra apenas a palavra buscada, se você retirar isso, mostra a linha toda do match.

-a = Processa o arquivo como se fosse texto.

-m 1 = Para de fazer novas buscas após o primeiro match verdadeiro

-h = Não mostra o nome do arquivo em que foi achado o match.

Comment: mas eu gostaria de fazer a substituição, eu consegui com o comando: `sed -i $(awk '/, past/{print NR;exit}' Report.html)'r test.txt' Report.html`

Comment: Parece-me que não está a resolver o pedido.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p0e  's/(, pasta)/"$1\n" . `cat teste.txt`/e ' Report.html
```

ou seja: substitui a primeira ocorrência de "`, pasta`"
pelo resultado de

```
eval("$1\n" . `cat teste.txt`)
```

(`perl -0 ... file` carrega o ficheiro todo; `s/ / /` faz apenas uma substituição)